# Reverse combinations into least number of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, reverse

If we have, for instance, these 9 combinations with 3 chars:

```
['ADG', 'ADH', 'BDG', 'BDH', 'CDG', 'CDH', 'AEG', 'AEH', 'AEI']
```

They can be compressed into the following two arrays:

```
[ ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D'], ['G', 'H'] ]

[ ['A'], ['E'],  ['G', 'H', 'I'] ]
```

which are able to create all combinations using dot product.

What is an effective algorithm for reversing combinations of any length into the least possible number of arrays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably want something along the lines of a NFA to DFA converter.

Comment: What is the dot product of two arrays? How exactly do you arrive at the two new arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach. The trivial decompositions are just one per letter. (`[['A'], ['D'], ['G']]` for `'ADG'`.) You start with these. You can merge two if they are only different in one position. (`[['A'], ['D'], ['G']]` + `[['A'], ['E'], ['G']]` = `[['A'], ['D', 'E'], ['G']]`) You try to merge everything to get valid decompositions.

Now you have all valid decompositions. But which ones to choose? I just try all 1-element choices, then all 2-element choices, etc. This will get expensive fast if we don't find a solution with just a few decompositions. But it works fine for the example!

```
def matches(a, b):
  return sum(1 if al == bl else 0 for (al, bl) in zip(a, b))

def subset(a, b):
  return all(al.issubset(bl) for (al, bl) in zip(a, b))

def combinations(lists):
  if len(lists) == 1:
    for e in lists[0]:
      yield [e]
  else:
    for e in lists[0]:
      for c in combinations(lists[1:]):
        yield [e] + c

def decompose(words):
  decomps = [[set(letter) for letter in word] for word in words]
  queue = decomps[:]
  while queue:
    a = queue.pop()
    for b in decomps:
      if len(a) == len(b) and matches(a, b) == len(a) - 1 and not subset(a, b) and not subset(b, a):
        merged = [al | bl for (al, bl) in zip(a, b)]
        if merged not in decomps:
          queue.append(merged)
          decomps.append(merged)
  decomps.reverse()  # Put larger decomps at the start.

  for n in range(1, len(words) + 1):
    for ps in combinations([decomps] * n):
      generated = set()
      for p in ps:
        generated.update(''.join(word) for word in combinations(p))
      if len(generated) == len(words):
        return ps

if __name__ == '__main__':
  words = ['ADG', 'ADH', 'BDG', 'BDH', 'CDG', 'CDH', 'AEG', 'AEH', 'AEI']
  for p in decompose(words):
    print p
```

It prints:

```
[set(['A', 'C', 'B']), set(['D']), set(['H', 'G'])]
[set(['A']), set(['E']), set(['I', 'H', 'G'])]
```